# selenium giving an unknown error when adding --headless option

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

so i have this code which makes requests to bing.com, but the problem is i need to deploy it on heroku but when i add the --headless argument which is required to run selenium on it i get a strange error which has to do with an extension i'm loading, it can't load the extension's background page the extension basically does half of the job, it could also be done manually nut it would take days to implement
here is the code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from data import *
from time import sleep




def main(mail: str, password: str):

    options = Options()
    
    options.add_extension(CRXPATH)
    options.add_argument(EDGE)
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverpath, options=options)
    driver.get(URL)


    #login
    # wait for email field and enter email
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(EMAILFIELD)).send_keys(mail)

    # Click Next
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()

    # wait for password field and enter password
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(PASSWORDFIELD)).send_keys(password)

    # Click Login
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()

    # Click NO
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NO)).click()
    sleep(5)


    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(ACCEDI)).click()

    sleep(5)
    
    driver.get(REWARDS)

    sleep(5)
    


    
    #Missions
    for i in range(1,4):
        while True:
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath(MISSIONS.format(i)).click()
                break
            except Exception:
                driver.refresh()
                sleep(10)

                
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
        sleep(45)
        
        for i in range(len(driver.window_handles)-1):
            driver.close()
            sleep(0.5)
            
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
        sleep(5)

    for i in range(41):
        word = random.choice(words)
        driver.get(BING.format(word))
        sleep(3)

    driver.quit()




    Moptions = Options()
    Moptions.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
    Moptions.add_argument("--headless")
    mobile = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverpath, options=Moptions)
    mobile.get(URL)
    sleep(5)
    
    #login
    # wait for email field and enter email
    WebDriverWait(mobile, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(EMAILFIELD)).send_keys(mail)

    # Click Next
    WebDriverWait(mobile, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()

    # wait for password field and enter password
    WebDriverWait(mobile, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(PASSWORDFIELD)).send_keys(password)

    # Click Login
    WebDriverWait(mobile, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()

    # Click NO
    WebDriverWait(mobile, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NO)).click()
    sleep(5)

    #i0116
    WebDriverWait(mobile, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(ACCEDI_)).click()
    

    WebDriverWait(mobile, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(ACCEDI__)).click()

    sleep(10)

    mobile.get("https://bing.com")
    
    for i in range(41):
        word = random.choice(words)
        mobile.get(BING.format(word))
        sleep(3)

    mobile.quit()
```

here is the error:

```
  File "C:\Projects\Python\msrtest\main.py", line 130, in <module>
    main("daniele.collanicchia@gmail.com", "MiaoMiao123")
  File "C:\Projects\Python\msrtest\main.py", line 22, in main
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverpath, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://id/_generated_background_page.html
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://id/_generated_background_page.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding an extension to chromedriver via `options.add_extension(CRXPATH)` which is impossible for a headless browser.

You can either remove the extension and keep the headless browser, or remove the headless browser to use the extension.